# Edit a string which is different each time

Tags: php

I have a string stored in a variable, this string may appear in the next ways:

```
$sec_ugs_exp = ''; //Empty one
$sec_ugs_exp = '190'; //Containing the number I want to delete (190)
$sec_ugs_exp = '16'; //Containing only a number, not the one Im looking for
$sec_ugs_exp = '12,159,190'; // Containing my number at the end (or in beginning too)
$sec_ugs_exp = '15,190,145,86'; // Containing my number somewhere in the middle
```

I need to delete the 190 number if it exists and deleting also the comma attached after it unless my number is at the end or it is alone(there is no commas in that case)

So in the examples I wrote before, I need to get a return like this:

```
$sec_ugs_exp = '';
$sec_ugs_exp = '';
$sec_ugs_exp = '16';
$sec_ugs_exp = '12,159';
$sec_ugs_exp = '15,145,86';
```

Hope I explained myself, sorry about my English. I tried using preg_replace and some other ways, but I always failed in detecting the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My final attempt not using regex:

```
$codes = array_flip(explode(",", $sec_ugs_exp));
unset($codes[190]);
$sec_ugs_exp = implode(',', array_keys($codes));
```

Comment: Just tested this will all your given use cases and this works as intended.

Comment: Fixed, to handle @Xeoncross use case.

Answer (score 2):

A simple regex should [do the trick: `/(190,?)/`](http://rubular.com/r/bmuC708QCC):

```
$newString = preg_replace('/(190,?)/', '', $string);
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/TIW9D6

Or if you want to [prevent matches like](http://rubular.com/r/WFfT55T67G):

```
$sec_ugs_exp = '15,1901,86';
                   ^^^
```

You [could use](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UOJ8Ih):

```
(190(,|$))
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, but should work for you:

`str_replace(array(",190","190,","190"), "", $sec_ugs_exp);`

Note the order in the array is important.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers here account for numbers beginning or ending with `190`.

```
$newString = trim(str_replace(',,', ',', preg_replace('/\b190\b/', '', $string)), ',');
```

Comment: Would leave commas on start and end in this case: '190,50,1900,190,54,80,190' Using your answer the return is: ,50,1900,54,80,

Comment: @Karevan, added a trim to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = explode ( ',' , $sec_ugs_exp );

foreach ( $array AS $key => $number )
{
  if ( $number == 190 )
  {
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
}

$sec_ugs_exp = implode ( ',' , $array );
```

This will work if a number if 1903 or 9190

Answer (score 0):

try

```
str_replace('190,', '', $sec_ugs_exp);
str_replace('190', '', $sec_ugs_exp);
```

or

```
str_replace('190', '', $sec_ugs_exp);
str_replace(',,' ',', $sec_ugs_exp);
```

if there are no extra spaces in your string